# Retrieve data from database and save it in a variable to do some calculation and diplay it

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to retrieve the last inserted id(id is in auto increment) from the database table named table facility and want to do some calculation(for example I am adding five now) and display the result on the screen. kindly help me I am not able to get this.

```
 <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{ 

$sql="SELECT MAX(facilityid) FROM tblfacility ";
$result=$dbh -> query($sql);
$row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<pre>", print_r($row),"</pre>";
echo $result ;
$code = $row->facilityid;
$sampleid= $code +5;
echo $sampleid;

} 
?>
```

Comment: What part of the code is the problem?

Comment: it is showing only last inserted id  (for example it is 100).i need it should also show 100+5=105

Comment: What does `$sampleid` shows? Also 100?

Comment: it does not show any thing  my output is Array
(
    [MAX(facilityid)] => 100
)
1

Comment: Incidentally, there is no sensible why you'd ever want to do this.

Comment: @DKJOSHI  What does `$sampleid` shows?

Comment: @Strawberry Iwant to retrieve that id and further want to generate some code based on that id

Comment: what is the output of `$row;` @DKJOSHI

Comment: That's just not something you'd ever need to do. Leave the ids alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{ 

$sql="SELECT MAX(facilityid) As facilityid FROM tblfacility ";
$result=$dbh -> query($sql);
$row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$code=$row[facilityid];
$sampleid= $code +1;
echo $sampleid;

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not alias max function to facilityid, so could  not call $row->facilityid you should

```
SELECT MAX(facilityid) As facilityid FROM tblfacility
```

Also, let use PDO::FETCH_OBJ  to get $row as object.

Comment: Because you get value witt object type "$row->facilityid". But you are using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, it will return array result. You should PDO::FETCH_OBJ to return object.